# Windows XP can't find external harddisk

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive

I have a Western Digital Elements harddisk, and a couple of weeks ago I plugged it into my desktop computer. It worked perfectly, then a couple of hours later I was going to plug it into my laptop, it worked perfectly fine.

But here's the problem, when I once again plugged it into my desktop computer, the computer didn't find it. I can't find it in "My Computer".

What should I do? I don't want to lose files on that disk.

Comment: What operating system you are using?

Comment: @Olli Windows XP :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also open Disk Manager(right click My Computer-Manage)  and see if it has found the disk but it is seen a "foreign" and needs to be imported.  Have also seen the disk unavailable as the drive letter it tries to use is in use with a mapped drive or removable media.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible the enclosure has malfunctioned and the hard drive is fine and your data is still there.

You would need to [disassemble the enclosure](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=disassemble+remove+hard+drive+WD+Elements&hl=en&prmd=ivns&source=univ&tbs=vid:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=nyVtTa6dK8GqlAeP-dHABA&ved=0CBkQqwQ) to remove the hard drive that is inside, then

connect the hard drive to your PC using a [hard drive to usb adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812119152&cm_re=usb_hard_drive_adapter-_-12-119-152-_-Product), see if you can read the data using Windows explorer

If this does not allow you to read the hard drive, then you would need to [pay a service](http://lowcostrecovery.com/pricing.html) to recover your data.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer man. If someone comes up with a way to do it without disassembeling it i go that way, but if not i guess i have to do it like u said, thanks for the answer :)